# How to get Call number as well as the duration of the call made by a user in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I need to get the call number as soon as he makes the call from his android mobile and then when the call ends then i need the duration of the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create One broadcast receiver and write following in your receiver `onReceive()` method
this receiver return last record of your call but make some time delay so it can return current record.

```
Cursor c=context.getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null,android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
     int numberColumn = c.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int dateColumn = c.getColumnIndex(
    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE);

    // type can be: Incoming, Outgoing or Missed
    int typeColumn = c.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int DurationColumn = c.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
```

Write following Your `mainfest file`

```
<receiver android:name="Your Receiver">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In onRecieve put this

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
            for (String key : keys) {
                Log.i("MYAPP##", key + "="+ bundle.getString(key));
                if(bundle.getString(key).equals("IDLE"))
                {
}

}
```

Comment: How to catch the event when the call is made and when the call will be disconnected?