# Android CallLogs Listener

Tags: android

I want to write an application in which every call information should be logged. Till now I can log all incoming calls by making use of `PhoneStateListener` but   dont know how to listen outgoing calls. If anyone had worked on such issue please let me know the way how to do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look at following thread

[How to get Call number as well as the duration of the call made by a user in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030162/how-to-get-call-number-as-well-as-the-duration-of-the-call-made-by-a-user-in-and/9030522#9030522)

from the following thread you can fetch whether the call is incomng or outgoing or missed

```
 // type can be: Incoming, Outgoing or Missed
    int typeColumn = c.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Bindal, I have already used the same thing as u suggested . Anyways thanks for response ..